# java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@54d29105 returned null for URL:${db.url}

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-profiles, spring-profiles

I'm working with spring boot and project profile. I added some profile in my maven configuration (pom.xml) und i try to import the profile properties in the application.propertie but i get an exception.

Here a part of my pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.x.server.MainApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>profile-development</id>
                <properties>
                    <environment>dev</environment>
                    <db.username>me</db.username>
                    <db.password>testme</db.password>
                    <db.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</db.url>
                </properties>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                    <property>
                        <name>environment</name>
                        <value>dev</value>
                    </property>
                </activation>
            </profile>
```

The application properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=${db.url}
spring.datasource.username=${db.username}
spring.datasource.password=${db.password}
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

but i get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@5d1759fb returned null for URL:${db.url}
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:326)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
        ... 45 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

has someone any ideas?

Comment: how are you configuring the bean?  Can you show that class? I think you are missing the PropertySource.

Comment: i doesn't work with bean but i use the @EnableAutoConfiguration in the main class.

Comment: Ok. but where are your `${db.url}` and other similar properties defined?

Comment: I assume the same like @DeendayalGarg - In your application.properties file is the following property `spring.datasource.url=${db.url}` and that's not a valid url.

Comment: i defined the db.url in pom.xml. Check the profile env. <db.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</db.url>

Answer (score 0):

In your profile `profile-development` for (probably) development builds you define the `db.url`. But the error did not seem to resolve the expression `${db.url}`.

The most likely error is, that the build was not done with the right profile, or actually the other (default) profile(s) miss a `db.url`.

Comment: the dev-profile is the default profile and has the db.url. When i build, i call this command with the environment: mvn clean spring-boot:run -Denvironment=dev and get the same exception

Comment: And the generated (copied) application properties file in the target directory is not substituted (filtered)? Sorry then I do not know.